# Issue with action and onsubmit in form

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, action, onsubmit

I have a form in HTML where I have used onsubmit to validate input and action to call the URL on form submit. This is my HTML code:

```
<form  method="POST" onsubmit="return validateInput();" action="editConf" id="edit-form">

// HTML Form code
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <p id = "edit-footer" align="center"> </p>
    <button type="reset" onClick="resetForm()" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
 </div>
```

This is my script code:

```
function validateInput() {
// some validation code
$.ajax({

    url: "validate_credentials",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: document.getElementById('data') },
    dataType: 'json', // added data type

    success: function(res) {

        if (res && valid) {

            $("#bigerror").innerHTML = res;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

I am facing the issue that the URL in action completes its execution first so even if the form is not valid it is submitting. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous. `validateInput()` returns immediately after sending the request, it doesn't wait for the success functions.

Comment: How can I handle this situation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$.ajax` is asynchronous, you can't use the return value of the success function.

You need to prevent the default submission immediately, then call `submit()` in the success function.

Also, in the `data:` option you need to get the value of an input, the input element itself.

```js
function validateInput() {
  // some validation code
  $.ajax({

    url: "validate_credentials",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      data: $("#data").val()
    },
    dataType: 'json', // added data type

    success: function(res) {

      if (res && valid) {

        $("#bigerror").innerHTML = res;
        $("#edit-input").submit();
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

To prevent this from looping infinitely, because `submit()` runs the same validation function first, remove `onsubmit` from the form, and move it to the submit button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validateInput();">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: `return false` returns false for everything.

Comment: @kingforever — Yes, that's the point. Read the second half of the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: I have this pop-up (modal) which remains open because of this. If I print the `res` it is looping infinitely.

Comment: Try the change I just added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should prevent default event if you want to have custom async validation.

```
<form id="myForm"  method="POST" action="editConf" id="edit-form">
```

fix your script to

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', validateInput)
function validateInput(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //Here we stoped defauld submit event
// some validation code
$.ajax({

    url: "validate_credentials",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data: document.getElementById('data') },
    dataType: 'json', // added data type

    success: function(res) {

        if (res && valid) {

            $("#bigerror").innerHTML = res;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Now the form won't be submitted. But now you have to think how you want to send data of the form to the server. There are several variants.

1) You can get form data and send it with ajax imitating the form

2) You can store a flag somewhere marking your form valid and if it is valid don't stop submit the form from your script and don't stop the event.

Comment: `onsubmit="validateInput"` — Now the function won't be called at all